# Data in the form not getting using serialize() in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

below is the form in html file
**html file**

```
<blc:form value method=POST action="@{/cart/add}">
  ..... 
  .....
    <div>
      <input class="btn btn-success" type="button" value="Add to Cart" id="addToCart"/> <!-- submit button -->
    </div>
     <div id="productInCart"></div>
  ......
    </div>
</blc:form>
```

from the above form I need to send `ajax` request by getting action url and form data for the request processing.

**JavaScript**

```
$document.on('click','#addToCart',function(e){
alert('test1')
var url = $(this).button.parents('form').attr('action')
var data= button.parents('form').serialize()
alert("request data:-"+data)//control is not reaching up to here
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function(data){
             $("#productInCart").html("")
             $("#productInCart").html(data)
             alert('success')
          }
        error: function(){
             alert('fail')
          }
    });
});
```

Control is entering into function and printing `alert`. I am able to get action attribute value from the above form and unable to get  data I am using `serialize()` to get the form data. can anyone help me how to get the form data?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have an extra dot notation when reading data, also I'd use `closest` and not `parents` because it has a bit more expected behavior:

```
button.parents.('form').serialize()
--------------^ here
```

So:

```
button.closest('form').serialize()
```

And also, you're missing a comma here:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data
    ----------^ here
```

So:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    ...
```

Should work, it looks okay otherwise.

Comment: I am really sorry it's typo here, an edit made please check.

Comment: You also don't end your expressions with `;`. Make sure it's after each expression (at the end of the `serialize()` line for example)

Answer (score 0):

You did not define `button` in your code. As mentioned before you should use `closest` instead of `parents`, because `parents` targets multiple elements. Here is working example of what you are trying to do:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#submit', function() {
  var $button = $(this),
    $form = $button.closest('form'),
    url = $form.attr('action'),
    data = $form.serialize();

  $('#log').html('Url: ' + url + '<br/> data: ' + data)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="my/url">
  <input type="text" name='input' value='test value'>
  <input type="checkbox" name='a' value='1' checked>
  <input type="button" value='submit' id='submit'>
</form>

<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: thank you, i tried `$(this).parents('form').serialize()` it is working. I'll try as you suggested.